# Trying to join 2 tables with same column names

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to join 2 tables but they both have email and password and I want both of the tables to be joined as a new row and not next to each other

So instead of:

```
c.email         | c.password   | u.email       | u.password
company@mail.com  companypass  user@mail.com     userpass
```

I want it to be like

```
email              | password
company@mail.com     companypass
user@mail.com        userpass
```

This is the current query I have which leads to the first example:

```
SELECT 
      u.email, u.password, c.email, c.password 
FROM 
      korisnici_tbl AS u, companies_tbl AS c
```

Comment: I always get a little weary when I see the same data in two tables.  Can you share some more details on what you're ultimately trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want them to be in *different* rows, you can use a `UNION` (or `UNION ALL`, which allows duplicate rows)

```
SELECT email, password FROM companies_tbl
UNION ALL SELECT email, password FROM korisnici_tbl
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use a `UNION`:

```
SELECT email, password 
FROM korisnici_tbl 
UNION
SELECT email, password
FROM companies_tbl
```

If you want potential duplicate rows, use `UNION ALL` instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to keep rows from both tables, you do not need a join, you need a `UNION`:

```
SELECT u.email, u.password FROM korisnici_tbl AS u
UNION ALL
SELECT c.email, c.password FROM companies_tbl AS c
```

The `ALL` option will keep duplicates, if any are found in both tables. If you want duplicates removed, drop `ALL` from the `UNION`.